# Handler post delayed, random number and for cycles

Tags: android

Hello everyone I'm developping a game and I want that in a random period of time it show me some sprites so I did this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

    final int min = 5000;
    final int max = 25000;
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                //MyCODE  
            }
        }, i1);}

    }
```

But the problem is that when i used postDelayed it already define thirty times the time of i1 from now and then it show the sprites all together  .

What i want to do is:

```
 i1 = New random number between 5000-25000 -> first = run //MyCODE after "i1" seconds -> i1 = New random number between 5000-25000 -> second = run //MyCODE after "i1" seconds since "first" ........
```

Comment: Remove random initialization from the cycle

Comment: you are posting all runnables at the same time with delays ranging from 5000 to 25000. what you need to do is post the next runnable in the previous one

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is "every now and then" meaning, you're using Random.  Every now and then falls within the bounds of time, so it's completely possible to get them all at the same time.

ALSO, you're recreating the same Random() number generator with the same seed, so it will probably produce the same number the first time you call it. Random is never truly random.

Create one random object with a seed of the current time.  It will make it seem more random than it is.

```
Handler spriteHandler = new Handler(); // Keep this global to the scope of the class. You only need one.
final int MIN = 5000;
final int MAX = 25000;
Random r = new Random(System.getCurrentTimeMillis()); 

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        int i1 = r.nextInt(MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN;
        spriteHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //MyCODE  
            }
        }, i1);}
    }
```

If you **never** want them to show up at the same time, then you need to put in a algorithm that adjusts the time if one is already showing.  It'll be dependent on what you want though.